# Efficient Geodesic Nearest Neighbors

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, geospatial

Starting with latitude/longitude data (in radians), I’m trying to efficiently find the nearest n neighbors, ideally with geodesic (WGS-84) distance.

Right now I’m using [sklearn’s BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) with haversine distance (KD-Tres only take minkowskian distance), which is nice and fast (3-4 seconds to find nearest 5 neighbors for 1200 locations in 7500 possible matches), but not as *accurate* as I need. Code:

```
tree = BallTree(possible_matches[['x', 'y']], leaf_size=2, metric='haversine')
distances, indices = tree.query(locations[['x', 'y']], k=5)
```

When I substitute in a custom function for metric (`metric=lambda u, v: geopy.distance.geodesic(u, v).miles`) it takes an "unreasonably" long time (4 minutes in the same case as above). It’s documented that custom functions can take a long time, but doesn't help me solve my problem.

I looked at using a KD-Tree with ECEF coordinates and euclidian distance, but I’m not sure if that’s actually any more accurate.

How can I keep the speed of my current method, but improve my distance accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for why your metric is slow is that it written in Python while other metrics in sklearn are written in Cython/C++/C.

So as for instance discussed [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3071) for Random Forests or [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1701) you would have to implement your metric in Cython, fork your own version of [BallTree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.pyx) and include your custom metric there.