# How does sklearn's standard DBSCAN run so fast?

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I've been messing around with alternative implementations of DBSCAN for clustering radar data (like grid-based DBSCAN). Up to this point, I had been using sklearn's standard euclidean DBSCAN and it would run on 26,000 data points in less than a second. However, when  I specify my own distance metric, like this:

```
X = np.column_stack((beam, gate, time_index))
num_pts = X.shape[0]
epsilons = np.array([[beam_eps]*num_pts, [gate_eps] * num_pts, [time_eps] * num_pts]).T

metric = lambda x, y, eps: np.sqrt(np.sum((x/eps - y/eps)**2))
def dist_metric(x, y, eps):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x - y)**2))

db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=minPts, metric=dist_metric, metric_params={'eps': epsilons}).fit(X)
```

it goes from 0.36 seconds to 92 minutes to run on the same data.

What I did in that code snippet can also be accomplished with just transforming the data beforehand and running standard Euclidean DBSCAN, but I'm trying to implement a reasonably fast version of Grid-based DBSCAN, for which the horizontal epsilon varies based on distance from the radar, so I won't be able to do that.

Part of the slowness in the above distance metric is because of that division by epsilon I think, because it only takes about a minute to run if I use a 'custom metric' that's just Euclidean distance:

```
metric = lambda x, y: np.sqrt(np.sum((x - y)**2))
```

How does sklearn's euclidean DBSCAN manage to run so much faster? I've been digging through the code, but haven't made sense of it so far.

Comment: Are you sure that your Euclidian distance lambda was that fast? Because usually, I think the difference between custom metrics as Python function or lambda and the built in metrics is that they are implemented in Cython or even C or C++ directly, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50954829/6694255).

Comment: Another option is precalculating the matrix if you have enough space

Answer (score 3):

Because it uses an index.

Furthermore, it avoids the slow and memory intensive Python *interpreter*, but does all the work in native code (compiled from Cython). This makes a huge difference when dealing with lots of primitive data such as doubles and ints that the Python interpreter would need to box.

Indexes make all the difference for similarity search. They can reduce the runtime from O(n²) to O(n log n).

But while the ball tree index allows custom metrics, the cost of invoking the python interpreter for every distance computation is very high, so if you really want a custom metric, edit the cython source code and compile sklearn yourself. Or you can use ELKI because the Java JVM can compile extension code into native code when necessary; it does not need to fallback to slow interpreter callbacks like sklearn.

In your case, it will likely be much better to rather preprocess the data. Scale it prior to clustering.

Comment: Not directly an answer to the question, but the [open3d DBSCAN implementation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/pointcloud.html#DBSCAN-clustering) is about 2x faster than sklearn (34ms v 62ms on 10,000 points on my Intel i7)